# Ubuntu 13.10 kiosk mode with custom session not working

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk, mode

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm trying to enter kiosk mode in chromium right on boot, but nothing is working.

I've been using this method (http://nexxylove.tumblr.com/post/22690398464/ubuntu-web-kiosk-in-10-easy-steps)

```
Create ~/.xsession, add the following;
#!/usr/bin/env bash
chromium-browser
```

Then when I'm running startx in terminal, it just refreshes the desktop and chromium doesn't pop up.

I've also tried the method with customized session:

```
1) Open a file (gksu gedit /usr/share/xsessions/Firefox.desktop) and paste:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox (No effects)
Comment=This session only opens Firefox
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox -height 1200 -width 1600
Icon=
Type=Application
```

But it doesn't work either. When I click on this file, chrome (I've changed the names) pops up. What am I doing wrong? I've spent almost 3 hours on this, trying to resolve it, followed many tutorials.

---

Ok, figured it out. I created /.xsessionrc instead of .xsession and now it works flawlessly.

Comment: Ok I have something. When I use first method described above, go into console with ctrl+alt+f1 and then login to my kiosk user and run startx it goes into chromium browser with no problems. What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the built-in startup manager for this? Also, you might be interested in the `--kiosk` flag for Chromium.

Comment: Startup manager wasn't working for me and I want to restrict user to only using browser. I'm using kiosk flag, just this script up here was simplified to just get it to work.

Comment: I'm  trying to do a similar thing. In my particular case I get an error: `Xsession: unable to launch "/path/to/script argument" X session --- "/path/to/script argument" not found; falling back to default session.` This tells me that Ubuntu is trying to find a file `script\ argument` at `/path/to/`, which is not what I want it to do. Strangely enough, I have it working without an argument, and `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` works as intended, but not not what I need.